# DynamoDB: get list of items that were overwritten in batch write operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get the list of attributes that were overwritten in a DynamoDB batch operation, but it doesn't have this information in the response.

Is there anyway to get list of items that were overwritten when using batch write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**: The [API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) clearly list which information is returned and that's not among them.

If you need the before state, you have to do individual `PutItem` requests with the `ReturnValues` parameter set to `ALL_OLD` - [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html#DDB-PutItem-request-ReturnValues).